# How do I arrange IAP orders in App store?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to arrange IAP order in Appstore from lower to higher prices. Does anyone know what is a priority in order to arrange them? (reference name, product ID, Display name or else)

In iTunes connect, I did order them based on Reference name and expected them to be arranged the same orders in Appstore. Conversely, they have appeared differently.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't rely on ordering from the App Store directly and need to filter them yourself on the device.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean by filtering them on the device?